# How to remove NA value of legend when using R tidyterra?

Tags: raster, r, terra

I downloaded the MCD12Q1 data (land cover and category type data) by MODIStsp package, and I want to plot it using tidyterra package.

For example,

```
library(terra)
library(tidyterra)
library(tidyverse)
t <- rast(ncol=10,nrow=10,
          vals=sample(x=1:10,size=100,replace = T))
plot(t)
t[t==6] <- NA
plot(t)
text(t)
names(t) <- 'v'
f <- t %>%
  mutate(fac = as.factor(v))
plot(f)
ggplot()+
  geom_spatraster(data=f,
                  aes(fill=fac))+
  theme_bw()+
  scale_fill_cross_blended_d()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `na.translate=FALSE` in the scale function:

```
ggplot() + 
 geom_spatraster(data=f,aes(fill=fac)) +
 theme_bw() + 
 scale_fill_cross_blended_d(na.translate=FALSE)
```

[image]

Why isn't this documented? Well, `scale_fill_cross_blended_d` calls some other scale function, maybe `scale_fill_discrete` and the help for that says that `...` args are passed on to the scale type, but doesn't give any clues how to find out how to get help for the scale type, or have a "See Also" section but eventually (by searching the source code for `na.translate`, which I could only do because I knew what I was looking for) I found the general parameters for discrete scales via `?discrete_scale` which lists `na.translate` and other parameters that should work for all discrete scales.

`See Also: discrete_scale`  would save a lot of people a lot of searching and maybe I'll submit a documentation request.

Comment: Thanks, but why this parameter is not showed in the help package.

Comment: Hi, that’s not showed because that option is part of `ggplot2` system. The scales I provided in the package leverages on that

Comment: It is in fact defined via `…` on the man page where you can find a link to the underlying functions

Comment: Issues/PR welcomed https://github.com/dieghernan/tidyterra/issues/new/choose

Comment: I think the help for the scale being used here is fine, its just chasing down all the links and somehow finding `?discrete_scale` where the parameter is finally documented. If you are a ggplot new user you might look at `?scale_colour_discrete` but I can't find a path to `?discrete_scale`, just a twisty turny maze of passages.... Its a documentation PR to `ggplot2` that I'd want to make.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using tmap. Note my order of loading libraries, placing of functions, arguments and replacing == with %in%. This can be reproduced even more parsimoniously using other `tidyverse` functions I will then digress from the OP.

```
library(tmap)
library(tidyverse)

t <- rast(ncol=10,nrow=10,
          vals=sample(x=1:10,
                      size=100,
                      replace = T))

t[t %in% 6] <- NA

names(t) <- 'v'

tm_shape(t) +
  tm_raster() +
  tm_layout(
    legend.outside = TRUE)
```